# Stored Procedure in C# (ASP.NET CORE)

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

We have a stored procedure created in the database. It is working just fine but I am not able to figure out how to call it within my code. For some reason I keep getting back

> Procedure or function 'GetNextApplicationNumber' expects parameter '@ApplicationId', which was not supplied.

My code:

```
string connectionString = "THE_CONNECTION_STRING";
using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (IDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
     command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

     IDbDataParameter parameter = command.CreateParameter();
     parameter.ParameterName = "@ApplicationId";
     parameter.Value = applicationId;
     parameter.DbType = DbType.String;

     command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

     command.CommandText = "[dbo].[GetNextApplicationNumber]";

     connection.Open();

     using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
     {
          string applicationNumber = string.Empty;

          if (reader.Read())
          {
              applicationNumber = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
          }

          return applicationNumber;
     }
}
```

I have tried quite a few different ways (most of which seem to be outdated and no longer available).

Comment: You could try to use SQL Server Profiler to analize the SQL sent to your SQL Server. Try to not set the DbType property of your parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the `CommandText` property, it clears the parameters collection.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you are using the old ways.

Try this mate:

```
public string GetNextApplicationNumber(int applicationId)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("GetNextApplicationNumber", conn))
                    {

                        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ApplicationId", applicationId);
                        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        da.Fill(dt);

                        string applicationNumber = string.Empty;

                        applicationNumber = dt.Rows[0]["Column_Name"].ToString();

                        return applicationNumber;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: I am using .net core and it does not seem the SqlDataAdapter class is compatible with core :(

Answer (score 0):

Consider using this one:

```
public static SqlCommand WithParameter(this SqlCommand sqlCommand, SqlParameter parameter)
    {
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(parameter);
        return sqlCommand;
    }
```

and then

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[GetNextApplicationNumber]",sqlConnection)
                     .WithParameter(new SqlParameter("@ApplicationId", SqlDbType.BigInt) {Value = 1});

using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
 {...}
```